# PHP APC uptime problem

Tags: php, restart, apc, uptime

I am on [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) with [Alternative PHP Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators#Alternative_PHP_Cache) (APC). It worked fine until yesterday when I updated the website and changed a few [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) queries (I don't see how it would affect the APC opcode cache.)

Today I see that the load has increased on the server and I see in Alternative PHP Cache, that the uptime of APC is somewhere around 15 minutes and then it gets restarted.

At this point the APC cache is only about 20% full of the available 30 MB. Using for opcode cache only. During this 15 minutes the cache works fine (99,8% cache hits). After this unwanted restart the APC cache is empty. Why is it restarting? Where can I find the logs for it?

Comment: Happened again after 16 minutes...

Comment: serverfault may be able to help

Comment: yeah I realized... by the way it was a cpanel update that caused apache to restart gracefully every 15 minutes

Comment: Sounds like you resolved your issue.  You should probably submit your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [cPanel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) update that caused Apache to restart gracefully every 15 minutes.

Comment: If you get a chance I was wondering if you could clarify what sort of cPanel update was causing Apache to gracefully restart every 15 minutes?